# Conversion of very large numbers to varchar in Oracle string concatenation

Tags: oracle

I am supporting an application whose data storage recently moved from Oracle 9i to 12c.  After this migration, a problem emerged in occasional queries that retrieve very large numbers as part of a string concatenation. Assuming a table with the definition

```
mytable{
test1 number,
test2 number
}
```

with one row with values

```
test1 = 100000000000000000000 and test2=100
```

In 9i I could run a query `select test1||','||test2 from mytable` and get result

```
100000000000000000000,100
```

In 12c I get ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.

Here is the relevant portion of the stack trace:
 java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number

```
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:195)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:876)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1175)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1296)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1498)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatementWrapper.java:406)
```

Here is a dump of two representative columns, the first one of which has the very large value, from 12c:  Typ=2 Len=3: cb,2,1   Typ=2 Len=5: bb,36,48,1a,4a

And the same dump from 9i: Typ=2 Len=3: cb,2,1  Typ=2 Len=5: bc,a,12,52,25

Since the string concatenation is in the database, I assume this behavior is not affected by configuration of sqlplus or some other client, but rather is determined in the server itself.  Is there some configuration that I can change in 12c or some data transformation call I should make in the select call to fix this problem?

Comment: Worked for me. Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: You received the correct concatenated value?  I am thinking there is some server-side configuration setting that controls this.

Comment: Yup.  Try to_char(test1)||','||to_char(test2)

Comment: It still returns the ORA-01722 message

Comment: What exactly throws that message - are you seeing it with a simple query in SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer (or some other client), or for instance in a Java app that is doing an implicit conversion when it fetches the data, such as with resultSet.getInt()? It looks like you expect a string really, but NLS settings could effect an app that is mistakenly treating it as a number at some point. If it's a basic client, which one, and which version, and how are you executing the query?

Comment: I originally hit the error in a java program and have been reproducing it with sql developer.  I never get the opportunity to make any resultset calls in Java since the executeQuery call throws an exception.

Comment: Can you recreate this reliably with the sample table you've shown in the question, or only with a real table? What does `select dump(test1, 1016) as d1, dump(test2, 1016) as d2 from mytable` show? (My only guess at the moment is that you have a corrupt value in your table, but that's unlikely, particularly if it is reproducible with a new table).

Comment: Interesting questions.  You're right--my artificial example actually works properly.  However, I see the problem on multiple columns and multiple tables in my database.

Comment: what is the exact query causing the problem?  What is the ddl of the tables causing the problem?  I'll take a stab at it.  You actually have a table that has a column that is VARCHAR2 and you are doing WHERE value = 100.  This would cause an implicit conversion of all the strings to numbers, but you have data in the strings that are not numeric.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the output of dump.  Here is the first row of dump for data that likely fails in the actual query.  The first column is the problematic one: Typ=2 Len=3: cb,2,1 Typ=2 Len=5: bb,36,48,1a,4a

Comment: I guess if you moved data form 9i to 12 you used legacy `exp`/`imp`? You can get corruption with that, and if that is what has happened it sounds like it might be widespread. If you're able to, maybe find a value in the old 9i instance and it's matching value in the 12c instance, see how SQL Developer displays them both, and also how each is dumped?

Comment: I will have to check with the DBA on the mechanism for making the new database.  I have confirmed that for equivalent cases 9i works and 12c does not.  Here is the equivalent dump from the 9i: Typ=2 Len=3: cb,2,1 Typ=2 Len=5: bc,a,12,52,25

Comment: Yeah, that looks corrupt, that final 1 should not be there I think. Dumping your first value should give you just `Typ=2 Len=2: cb,2`. So the question becomes... how did it get corrupted? And what, if anything, can you do about it? It would be interesting to see what the actual number was in 9i for that row, if that's available. Is this a trial migration, or are you committed to this 12c instance already?

Comment: `bc0a125225` is 0.0000000009178136. I'm confused by your 9i comment though, is that showing `cb0201` as well, or was that just in 12c? Maybe you can update the question with all this stuff to make it clearer?

Comment: The 1 is present in the dumps from both databases, right?  Does that mean the 9i database is corrupt also?  The actual value in this case is 100000000000000000000.

Comment: I added the dumps to the problem description.  My DBA is doing a manual copy of one of the tables from 9i to another 12c schema to see if the problem is still present without the migration tool.

Comment: Yes, it seems your 9i data is corrupt too. Found an ancient 9i DB I could spin up. Forcing that invalid number value into the table in the same way shows that is is stored the same way you're seeing, but does not error in that environment. Very interesting. Doesn't help you at all, but still... might be time for your DBA to talk to Oracle.

Comment: Yep, thanks for your help.  If you want to summarize your suggestions as an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have corrupt data in your database, unfortunately; and it sounds like it was already corrupt in 9i, rather than corrupted during migration (presumably via `exp`/`imp`).

You can demonstrate the problem by forcing the inserting of invalid data (don't do this on a real table):

```
SQL> create table mytable(test1 number, test2 number);

Table created.

SQL> declare
  l_test1 number;
  l_test2 number;
begin
  dbms_stats.convert_raw_value('cb0201', l_test1);
  dbms_stats.convert_raw_value('bc0a125225', l_test2);
  insert into mytable(test1, test2) values (l_test1, l_test2);
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select test1||','||test2 from mytable;
select test1||','||test2 from mytable
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number

SQL> select dump(test1, 1016) as d1, dump(test2, 1016) as d2 from mytable;

D1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
D2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=2 Len=3: cb,2,1
Typ=2 Len=5: bc,a,12,52,25
```

Running the same test in 9i does not throw the same error, even though the raw data in the table is invalid:

```
SQL> select test1||','||test2 from mytable;

TEST1||','||TEST2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
100000000000000000000,.0000000009178136

1 row selected.

SQL> select dump(test1, 1016) as d1, dump(test2, 1016) as d2 from mytable;

D1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
D2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=2 Len=3: cb,2,1
Typ=2 Len=5: bc,a,12,52,25
```

The dump value showing as `cb,2,1` should not have that last byte (1). If you dump the actual number, in either version, you get:

```
SQL> select dump(100000000000000000000, 1016) from dual;

DUMP(100000000000
-----------------
Typ=2 Len=2: cb,2
```

and if you populate the table using that number, instead of forcing in the corrupt value, it works as expected in both versions too.

It's possible a previous export/import in 9i has caused the problem, or an OCI program has caused it (there may be other ways too). Without know when and how the data was corrupted, I'd have to question how much you can trust it, and how recoverable it is. It may be possible to clean it up, but without know what the correct values are it sounds a bit risky.

You may need to involve Oracle support to help you analyse the issue further and suggest a way to recover; though as 9i is so old that in itself may be difficult now.

Comment: It looks like the original values put into the db were things like 100000002004087730000 and were loading as 100000000000000000000